# TextView is not showing proper text from string resources.

Tags: android, android-layout

I have below string resources in my android studio project.

```
<string name="not_registered">Haven&#39;t registered yet?</string>
```

I set the string into TextView with following code:-

```
android:text="@string/not_registered"
```

It show proper text in xml preview window as expected:-

### Haven't registered yet?

But when i run the project then it doesn't show the text after special char " **'** ".
It only show

### Haven

I am not able to understand why it is not showing full string.

Comment: did you try using `\'`, instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, change into your string resource.

```
<string name="not_registered">Haven\'t registered yet?</string>
```

And set the string into TextView with following code:-

```
android:text="@string/not_registered"
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `<string name="not_registered">Haven\'t registered yet?</string>` instead of 
`<string name="not_registered">Haven&#39;t registered yet?</string>`

Answer (score 2):

As per [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#FormattingAndStyling). spacial character Single quote (')
cab be used any way of the following:

- \'
- Enclose the entire string in double quotes ("This'll work", for example)

In your case You can use as follows

```
<string name="not_registered">Haven\'t registered yet?</string>
<string name="not_registered">"Haven't registered yet?"</string>
```

both way will work.

Answer (score 1):

All of the below code look fine in preview:

```
<string name="not_registered">Haven&#39;t registered yet?</string>
<string name="not_registered">Haven&apos;t registered yet?</string>
<string name="not_registered">Haven\'t registered yet?</string>
```

but only the 3d works!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
 <string name="not_registered">Haven\'t registered yet?</string>
```

it's working

Answer (score 1):

```
<string name="not_registered">Haven\'t registered yet?</string>
```